# Showing a full text on tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a long text that I want to show on treeview but it shows only the first part of the text and then the other rows in the same way

```
from tkinter import ttk

top = Toplevel()

top.title('Results')
    
tre = ttk.Treeview(top)

tre["columns"]=(["time","text","test","group"])

tre.column("#0",width=0)
tre.column("time",anchor=CENTER,width=120)
tre.column("text",anchor=CENTER,width=200)
tre.column("test",anchor=CENTER,width=120)
tre.column("group",anchor=CENTER,width=120)

tre.heading("time",text='time',anchor=CENTER)
tre.heading("text",text='text',anchor=CENTER)
tre.heading("test",text='test',anchor=CENTER)
tre.heading("group",text='group',anchor=CENTER)

for row in df.itertuples(False):
    tre.insert('',0, values=(row))
    
tre.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)

mainloop()
```

Comment: code incomplete

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).